# How can I sort a Firebase database in chronological order?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I am making an app that has posts and comments on said posts. However, whenever a user posts/comments they are not shown in the order they were posted after loaded in a UITableView. I have implemented a timestamp into the posts and comments, but I can't figure out how to sort them.

My Database:

```
"posts" : {
   "47CCC57D-9056-4F5B-919E-F686065574A2" : {
     "comments" : {
        "99838A46-A84E-47E9-9D9C-E048543DC7C9" : {
          "comment" : "Would you trade for a red one?",
          "timestamp" : 1488315280579,
          "commentID" : "99838A46-A84E-47E9-9D9C-E048543DC7C9",
          "username" : "user"
        }
     },
     "description" : "Don't really need this anymore. Willing to go for less if I can get a trade",
     "image" : "JLMzSuhJmZ.jpeg",
     "postID" : "47CCC57D-9056-4F5B-919E-F686065574A2",
     "price" : "$5",
     "rating" : "8",
     "title" : "title",
     "uid" : "5U1TnNtkhegmcsrRt88Bs6AO4Gh2",
     "username" : "user"
},
```

How I am atttempting to sort comments in `CommentViewController`:

```
var postDetails: String?
var posts = NSMutableArray()   

func loadData() {
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postDetails!)
              .child("comments").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
              .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    for post in postsDictionary {
                        self.posts.add(post.value)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
   })
}


 // Displays posts in postsDetailsTableView
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
       // Configure the cell...
       let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
       cell.selectionStyle = .none
       cell.commentLabel.text = post["comment"] as? String
       cell.usernameLabel.text = post["username"] as? String
       return cell
   }
}
```

What can I do so that each comment is in the order it was posted?

Answer (score 1):

The problem: In your code, you are returning the snapshot but then converting it to a dictionary which looses the ordering.

When querying by .value, the keys, values and information about the ordering are contained in the snapshot but the ordering is lost once the snapshot is converted to a dictionary so you need to iterate over the children to get the correct order.

```
func loadData() {
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postDetails!)
              .child("comments").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
              .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

               for child in snapshot.children {
                 print("child \(child)")
               }
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. Should I replace `func loadData` with your example or should I add the code to the existing function?

Comment: @gabe Either way. Obviously you will need to remove my print statement, which was to demonstrate the correct order, and replace it with the code to append whatever you need to the array. After that loop is done, self.tableView.reloadData(). The key is iterating over the snapshot.children to maintain the correct order.